# Use same object instance(log) in diffrent files

Tags: logging, go

I use logrus logger and I init it inside my main function like following

```
main.go file content


import "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"

var logger                *logrus.Logger

func init() {

    logger = utils.InitLogs()
}



func main(){

    logger.Info("bla bla")

   }
```

And I was able to use it  e.g.`logger.info(“test”)` in the main file, now I don’t want to create the `init` file in each
other file which need to use the logger , I want to use in other project file the same instance which I’ve created in the main.go file
How should I do it in golfing ?

**Im not asking about sharing it on the same package**

Comment: `logger` is visible in all source files within the same package.

Comment: @dev.bmax - thanks but I dont ask on the same package....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some points here:

Go groups files in package concept for example if you have some .go files in a directory with the `package main` that means that all files are sharing the package scope, in this case the `func init()` inits the `var logger` that is present in the `main` package.

I prefer to not use package scope variables, but this depends on your implementation
https://dave.cheney.net/2017/06/11/go-without-package-scoped-variables

Maybe you wanted to use logger in different package for example `github.com/youruser/work`

I prefer to pass the object log to the functions or methods you wanted to use it (as parameters or receiver)

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/user/utils"
    "github.com/user/work"
)

func main() {
    logger := utils.InitLogs()
    work.Do(logger)
}
```

or using as receiver

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/user/utils"
    "github.com/user/work"
)

func main() {
    logger := utils.InitLogs()
    w := work.New()
    w.Log = logger
    w.Do()
}
```

then in Do() you can log using the receiver

in the work package you should add it as filed

```
type Worker struct {
    Log *logrus.Logger
}
```

I really hope you can find it useful.

**update:**
An example of work package

```
package work

import "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"

type Worker struct {
    Log *logrus.Logger
}

func New() *Worker {
    return new(Worker)
}

func (w *Worker) Do() {
    // some work
    // Here you are passing as receiver parameter
    w.Log.Info("bla bla")
}

func AnotherFunc(log *logrus.Logger) {
    // Here you are passing as method parameter
   log.Info("bla bla")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so in this case I need to create constructor for module b(from different package ) ? can you also provide the code which I should use in the work package ?

Comment: You should create the logger only one, sure I will update my answer

Comment: Ok thanks, so just to see if I get it right, Before I call to the module B (from different package) I need to call to the new method and pass the logger and then use the logger inside this module, am I right?

Comment: If you want to use it as receiver yes, you also can pass it as parameter, I'm adding another func in my answer

Comment: Ohh, So I should pass it in every function ? its not better to get it from the `New` method and somehow keep it ? and then re-use it ?

Comment: The main point here is, if you want to use a `var` in another package you should pass it to other package, there are no Universal scope. or another option is create a new logger when you need it, but this is not good performance practice